# Grails Hibernate Criteria: How do I specify multiple criteria for one association?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, criteria, detachedcriteria

**Edit 1:** To further clarify my problem, I updated my example code so that only one property is relevant.

In the grails documentation, the following example is given [in the Criteria section](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria) under querying associations:

> We can query [...] association[s] by using the property name transactions as a builder node:

```
def c = Account.createCriteria()
def now = new Date()
def results = c.list {
    transactions {
        between('date', now - 10, now)
    }
}
```

> The above code will find all the Account instances that have performed transactions within the last 10 days [...].

This is all great, **but how do I do more complex queries for associations?** I mean, not everytime I want to say

*query all domain objects that have at least one associated object that satisfies my condition*,

but rather

*query all domain objects that have at least one associated object that satisfies my condition AND that have at least one associated object that satisfies another condition*.

Here is the criteria I tried to use to address the latter case. It does not work.

```
new DetachedCriteria(ParentDomainClass).build{
    associatedObjectsOfChildClass {
        eq 'someProp', 'value'
    }
    associatedObjectsOfChildClass {
        eq 'someProp', 'otherValue'
    }
}.list()
```

When I execute this code, only one of the association criteria is considered. I think it is not allowed to have multiple subqueries for the same association. But if that's the case, how can I restrict this further?

The following code yields the expected result, but it is not entirely achieved at database level.

```
new DetachedCriteria(ParentDomainClass).build{
    associatedObjectsOfChildClass {
        eq 'someProp', 'value'
    }
}.list().intersect(new DetachedCriteria(ParentDomainClass).build{
    associatedObjectsOfChildClass {
        eq 'someProp', 'other_value'
}}.list())
```

Here is a solution in native MySQL:

```
select * from parent_object
where id in(
    select parent_id from child_object
    where some_prop = "value"
)
and id in (
    select parent_id from child_object
    where some_prop = "other_value"
)
```

How do I achieve that using only criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Check the sql query logs for this. You can log the query by adding logSql=true in dataSource.groovy or set this property in yml file for Grails 3.

Have you tried

```
Account.createCriteria().list{
    associatedObjectsOfChildClass {
        eq 'someProp', 'value'
        eq 'otherProp', 'otherValue'
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already enabled SQL logging. That does not really help me for I don't know what criteria query yields my desired SQL query. Please check my comment on [Bhushan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37888901/3025256) for why this code you provided does not help in my case.